# How to use Q.all with delay?

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I have a bunch of functions in an array `allFunctions`. I want them to be executed one after the other with delay between them. The closest I can think of is:

```
result = Q();

allFunctions.forEach(function(fn) {
  result = result.then(fn).delay(1000);
})
```

Is this possible to do with the `Q.all` syntax?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in a meaningful way, a promise is an already started operation and `Q.all` waits for all actions to finish together.

What you currently have is the common way to do this, and it's very similar to the synchronous version (a for loop with sleep).

You can shorten it a bit with `Array.prototype.reduce` though:

```
var result = allFunctions.reduce(function(prev,fn){
    return prev.then(fn).delay(1000);
},Q());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can nest between your functions a `Q().delay( 1000 )`

This means that you would have to map your function array to:

```
function delay(){ return Q.delay(1000); }

var functions = [ f1, delay, f2, delay, f3 ];
```

`Q.all` will not run your functions sequentially, what you are doing with `prev.then` is an interesting hack, but you can also run it the way Q suggests it (more info here https://github.com/kriskowal/q#sequences):

```
var results = functions.reduce(Q.when, Q(initialVal));
```

Having the delays intercallated in your function array will also provide more control over the delays (if you eventually want different time delays)

Comment: Both of you wrote the 'correct' answer. I awarded the other question as it was the first one. Sorry. :/

Comment: I would certainly not call chaining promises with `then` a hack. It is an extremely common practice in promise code bases. Doing Q.when is just the static counterpart of `then`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I was talking of doing the reduce with the new function that places a then on the previous :) No the use of the then itself